# Why use GROUP BY in WINDOW FUNCTION

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, aggregate-functions, window-functions

Im currently working with the northwind database and want to see the companies with more orders place in 1997. Im being ask to use windows function so i wrote this

```
select c.customerid,
       c.companyname,
       rank() over (order by count(orderid) desc )
from customers c
inner join orders o on c.customerid = o.customerid
where date_part('year',orderdate) = 1997;
```

However this code ask me to use GROUP BY with c.customerid. And i simply don't understand why. Supposedly this code will give me all the customers id and names and after that the window function kicks in giving them a rank base on the amount of orders. So why group them?

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
rank() over (order by count(orderid) desc )
```

You have an aggregate function in the `over()` clause of the window function (`count(orderid)`), so you do need a `group by` clause. Your idea is to put in the same group all orders of the same customer:

```
select c.customerid,
       c.companyname,
       rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as rn
from customers c
inner join orders o on c.customerid = o.customerid
where o.orderdate = date '1997-01-01' and o.orderdate < '1998-01-01'
group by c.customerid;
```

Notes:

- Filtering on literal dates is much more efficient than applying a date function on the date column
- `count(orderid)` is equivalent to `count(*)` in the context of this query
- Postgres understands functionnaly-dependent column: assuming that `customerid` is the primary key of `customer`, it is sufficient to put just that column in the `group by` clause
- It is a good practice to give aliases to expressions in the `select` clause
- Another good practice is to prefix all columns with the (alias of) table they belong to

Comment: thx mate. I see now why the group by needs to be here. And thanks for the tips too!

Answer (score 1):

You would use it correctly in an *aggregation* query.  That would be:

```
select c.customerid, c.companyname, count(*) as num_orders,
      rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as ranking
from customers c inner join 
     orders o
     on c.customerid = o.customerid
where date_part('year',orderdate) = 1997
group by c.customerid, c.companyname;
```

This counts the number of orders per customer in 1997.  It then ranks the customers based on the number of orders.

I would advise you to use:

```
where orderdate >= '1997-01-01' and
      orderdate < '1998-01-01'
```

For the filtering by year.  This allows Postgres to use an index if one is available.